# How I can send UDP multicasts over all connected networks?

Tags: sockets, networking, udp, multicast

I have three network interfaces (under my Window 7)

```
192.168.0.2   - real network card (interface id: 10)
192.168.180.1 - vmware adapter 1 (interface id: 21)
192.168.139.1 - vmware adapter 2 (interface id: 22)
```

I have UDP socket (AF_INET), which is not bound to any addr by bind call.

I try to send datagrams to 239.255.255.250. As I can see in Wireshark, only 192.168.139.1 source addr used to send datagram over 192.168.139.0/24 network.

I think I need to tell to winsock from which interface it must send datagrams and try to call setsockopt:

```
UINT adapterId = 10;
setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_MULTICAST_IF, (char*)&adapterId, sizeof(adapterId));
```

but I got an 10049 (WSAEADDRNOTAVAIL) error here.

How I can send my datagrams over my real network, or over all networks for my multihomed host?

Long time ago my code (but without setsockopt call) was work fine under WinXP, but I can't remember, has that system one network adapter or multiple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track. You have to loop over all the NICs sending via each one in turn as per your code above. The 10049 is caused by specifying a bad address, or an address that isn't local to this host. In this case you're incorrectly passing an adapter ID instead of an IP address.

Comment: Problem was stupid. I read the wrong documentation, which tells me that the IP_MULTICAST_IF adapterId must be in host byte order, not in network. In other docs I found difference in this point, and add htonl. After that, setting IP_MULTICAST_IF will not fail and all datagrams are sent to all networks

Comment: In fact you can do `IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP` specifying the NIC's IP address at the same time in a single call, in the `ip_mreqn.imr_address` field.